# How to get query.whereKey(key, containedIn: [Array]) to work with relation.query

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject, pfrelation

I am querying both the local data store and the server for `PFObjects`. To try and save mobile data usage and networking usage, the data is first looked up in the local data store and then whatever has not been found is looked up on the server.

The code to figure out which `PFObject`s have not been found yet is:

```
let response = objects as! [PFObject]
var responseObjectIds = [String]()
for x in response {
    responseObjectIds.append(x.objectId!)
}
query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: responseObjectIds)
```

This seems to work fine with normal queries, but breaks down when trying to do the same thing with queries created from `Relations`.

I think I read somewhere that the `whereKey` method implementations are slightly different for `Relation` queries, but I don't think it is very well documented.

Any help improving the code or suggesting new solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The query on a relational column will be expecting a PFObject and not a string/(in this case) an array of strings, I believe.

You will need something like the following:

```
let relation = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "yourClassName", objectId: response.objectId)
query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: relation)
```

Comment: So how would I modify the last line, `query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: responseObjectIds)` to create this restraint correctly for a `Relation` query?

Comment: I understand that it needs an array of PFObjects to check against, but what should I pass in as the key?

Comment: please see revision above which may help